# Twitter bootstrap btn-large in navbar

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I can't get a proper sized btn-large button in my navbar.
Tried changing the navbarHeight & baseLineHeight less variables but that didn't help.
Buttons are smaller than the ones used outside the navbar.

```
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="container">
            <a title="" class="btn btn-primary btn-large" href=""><i class="icon-plus-sign icon-white"></i>Add</a>
                <ul class="nav pull-right">
                <li class="divider-vertical">
                <li><a href="">Val</a></span></li>
                <li class="divider-vertical">
                <li><a href="">Val2</a></li>
                <li class="divider-vertical">
                <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">val3<i class="icon-user"></i></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="">My account</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/accounts/logout/">Log out</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
            </div>
       </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is by design, since the navbar height is standard (to accommodate the other elements around it). You can overwrite that limitation by creating your own class and "forcing" the padding of the `.btn-large` to be shown, like so:

```
.navbar .btn-large-navbar {
    padding: 9px 14px;
}
```

Then you can add the new class to your large button:

```
<a title="" class="btn btn-primary btn-large btn-large-navbar" href=""><i class="icon-plus-sign icon-white"></i>Add</a>
```

Keep in mind though that since you're stretching the navbar some elements might look out of place.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/gnEAe/